# VB.NET Post Data not being received

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

Hoping someone can help with this frustrating problem I have found myself battling with.

I have set up, what will be a payment response page in a VB.net website, the page receives POST data to process (from the payment gateway).

However it seems when the response page is called and data posted to it, the following outputs nothing when attempting to dump one of the POST variables:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
Dim OrderID As String = Request("MC_Id")

            Response.Write(OrderID)
            Response.Write("done")
End Sub
```

I've tested posting to this page using the online site http://www.hurl.it/ which allows the generation of HTTP POST and GET requests. Get Requests seem to work fine.

I've also tried the following in addition:

Added the  to the system.web section in web.config

Added the ValidateRequest="false" directive to the page itself

Running on .NET 4.0

I;'m wondering if there is some kind of server setting preventing the POST data from being received, or something more simple that I have overlooked?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: have you checked the contents of the `Response.OutputStream`?

Comment: Have you tried listing all parameters it received (if any) using Request.Parameters... Or using Google Chrome debugger console to view Post data

Comment: Mike, I tried your suggestion and simply get the following as output "System.Web.HttpResponseStream" none of the post variables are output.

Comment: Don, I have tried numerous ways to grab hold of those POST vars, the trouble is, it seems the server or the app is stripping all POST data somewhere along the line.  I'm contemplating switching to GET instead for the time being but curious to solve this problem just for the sake of learning more about it